# Color Individual "Color By Number" Polygons

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, shapely

Here's this cool plot I have:

[image]

Generated using this code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from shapely.geometry import Point, LineString
from shapely.ops import unary_union, polygonize

from matplotlib.pyplot import cm
import numpy as np


def plot_coords(coords, color):
    pts = list(coords)
    x, y = zip(*pts)
    # print(color)
    plt.plot(x,y, color=color)
    plt.fill_between(x, y, facecolor=color)


def plot_polys(polys, color):
    for poly, color in zip(polys, color):
        plot_coords(poly.exterior.coords, color)


points = [Point(6, 0),
          Point(5, 1.72),
          Point(3, 1.73),
          Point(2, 0),
          Point(3, -1.73),
          Point(5, -1.73)]

# buffer points to create circle polygons

circles = []
for point in points:
    circles.append(point.buffer(2))

# unary_union and polygonize to find overlaps

rings = [LineString(list(pol.exterior.coords)) for pol in circles]
union = unary_union(rings)
result = [geom for geom in polygonize(union)]


# plot resulting polygons

colors = cm.rainbow(np.linspace(0, 1, len(result)))


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot()
fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.85)

for poly in result:
        centroidCoords = poly.centroid.wkt
        # print(centroidCoords)
        #plt.plot(centroidCoords)

# this part is really ugly, I can't figure out how to plot the coordinates from the above 
# for loop, the formatting is weird so I just formatted them manually, ugh. Some points are
# commented out because they are just slivers of barely visible polygons from slightly
# inaccurate math I guess

centroidCoords = [Point(7.210123936676805, -0.0014481952154823), #0
                  Point(5.817327756517152, -1.0513260084561042), #1
                  Point(5.603133733696165, -2.7765635631249412), #2
                  Point(4.500525247710033, -0.8659667639805515), #3
                  Point(3.9999999999880367, -2.089987631283091), #4
                  # Point(4.048137049179259, -0.0333070356040662), #5
                  # Point(4.0000092426053255, -0.0063886706458286), #6
                  Point(5.001117020126147, -0.0049682528095108), #7 
                  # Point(4.000014611322862, -0.000446001526914), #8
                  Point(5.815010886603158, 1.044998514899447), #9
                  # Point(4.000000218333326, 0.0000066644887113), #10
                  Point(4.500000000000001, 0.8649999999999999), #11
                  Point(4.001448625652675, 2.087475424328895), #12
                  Point(5.60401724850886, 2.7710509908378467), #13
                  # Point(3.997307724999615, -0.0049134134793138), #14
                  Point(3.4999775973742575, -0.8650387450203051), #15
                  # Point(3.995828825468981, -0.0025000872310011), #16
                  Point(2.1869624905370935, -1.0465658077069044), #17
                  # Point(3.949647552096463, 0.0246780865535455), #18
                  Point(2.9989568960908466, -0.0000271066971084), #19
                  Point(3.499481641504979, 0.8609597712896809), #20
                  Point(2.183590487640668, 1.0478993334094695), #21
                  Point(2.400064213432032, 2.777072141054654), #22
                  # Point(3.9997450166722692, -0.0000000000000001), #23
                  Point(0.7919163421701616, 0.0000000000000001), #24
                  # Point(3.999985388677139, -0.000446001526914), #25
                  Point(2.396866266303837, -2.776563563124941)] #26


plot_polys(result, colors)

for i in range(len(centroidCoords)):
    plt.scatter(centroidCoords[i].x,centroidCoords[i].y, marker="$"+str(i)+"$")

ax.set_aspect('equal')
plt.show()
```

So basically it starts with points, buffers them to polygons, intersects them as lines and creates polygons from all of the intersections. What I need to be able to do is tell matplotlib exactly which color to use for which polygon, and I'd like to use the hsluv python implementation. For example, I want to be able to say something like: Color outer polygons (0, 9, 13, 16, 17, and 2) blue, color polygon 6 purple, color polygon 11 yellow, etc.

I don't actually need the polygons numbered, but I was trying to figure out the order they were being plotted so I can hopefully tell each one what color to be.

There isn't much (any?) documentation or examples for how to use the [hsluv implementation in python](https://github.com/hsluv/hsluv-python), but I thought it was worth a shot. Even if the hsluv part isn't doable right now, at least figuring out how to control the color of each numbered polygon would be amazing!

Thank you for your time and skills!

Comment: I like the plot but I don't understand the question because it looks to me like you're already picking the colors of your polygons

Comment: Thank you! And...right. I am specifying the colors with colors = cm.rainbow(np.linspace(0, 1, len(result))) , and I could choose cm.viridis or some other pre-made palette, but I am not choosing which color goes to which polygon, am I? Like, how would I make polygon 0 pink and polygon 1 blue?

Comment: You don't have to sample a colormap, you can just cycle through a list of colors that you manually define if you prefer. So colors=['pink','blue',...]. Colors can be specified in several different ways including RGB - which is what pops out when you sample the colormap. Does that answer the question?

Comment: oh my god, yes. I was making it way harder than necessary. Tysm!